# Does Xrdp 0.9.5 only support IPV6 and not IPv4?

Tags: xrdp

My OS is ubuntu 18.04.5。Xrdp is 0.9.5

```
it@it51:~$ sudo netstat -ptan | grep xrdp
tcp6 0 0 ::1:3350 :::* LISTEN 4576/xrdp-sesman
tcp6 0 0 :::3389 :::* LISTEN 4587/xrdp
```

```
it@it51:~$ xrdp -v
xrdp: A Remote Desktop Protocol server.
Copyright (C) Jay Sorg 2004-2014
See http://www.xrdp.org for more information.
Version 0.9.5
```

Xrdp 0.9.5 only bind ipv6，Can it be bound to ipv4? If so, how should I configure it?

Answer (score 7):

**Use *port=tcp://:3389***
I managed to get IPv4 port listening on Ubuntu 20.04 with these steps:

1. `sudo nano /etc/xrdp/xrdp.ini`
2. Change `port=3389` to `port=tcp://:3389` & save,exit
3. `sudo systemctl restart xrdp`

I had setup xrdp with the *xrdp-installer* from [c-nergy.be](https://www.c-nergy.be/products.html)

Comment: Works as well with `Debian 11 bullseye` and brings up the rdp-server as `0.0.0.0:3389` instead of `:::3389` in `sudo netstat -tulpen`.